# Joystick driving from 'guest' in a multiplayer game?

Tags: ios, multiplayer, sphero-api

I'm trying replicate the TwoPhonesOneBall sample project using the RobotUISample joystick driving interface.  As I continue my investigation I'm worried that the remote player (the one not connected to the Sphero) won't be able to send RKDriveControl driveWithJoyStickPosition commands to the host then to the robot.

Right now i have it so the host can drive but the guest can't.  What's the difference between RKDRiveControl and RKDeviceCommands?  Is there any relationship between the 2 interfaces?

I know this is a vague question but any advice would be appreciated.  My code right now is a very close match to the 2 sample projects.  I can paste some if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

RKDriveControl is a convenience layer that allows you to give the joystick position information and it drives the robot. All it does in the background is calculate the RKRollCommand (an RKDeviceCommand) based on the joystick's position in the circle. You should be able to calculate the RKRollCommand yourself if needed.